# VS code and Svelte for vscode extension ERROR

Tags: typescript, svelte, vscode-extensions

I have a problem, when i launch vscode, everything is fine, i can find definitions for paths, i can use ctrl + click on path and it finds where is the code from. But immediately when extension Svelte for VS Code is loaded, no definitions can be found and i cant use ctrl + click to paths in .TS/.JS files (inside .SVELTE files it works properly)
When i uninstall extension Svelte for VS Code, it works!

Does anyone know, what is the problem?
Do i have wrong paths in my IOS?

I expect that i will be able to find definitions.

Comment: Consider opening an issue, if there is none, in the [respective repository](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools), providing all necessary system/app versions and a minimal repository reproducing the issue.

Comment: Got the exact same problem since yesterday, will take a look around and raise an issue in their repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue - I set up a bare bones svelte / rollup / ts project , and it wouldn't build, complaining about `import App from App.svelte`. After a quick google, the solution seemed to be to add a `global.d.ts` file containing a reference to svelte types

```
/// <reference types="svelte" />
```

This fixed my build error, however vscode was still complaining about the import:

[image: 1]

I was experiencing the same situation you described, where uninstalling the svelte extension would fix the problem. I tried some different versions of the extension but it still complained. So I had a look through the extension settings and came across this:

[image: 2]

Turning this on, and a quick 'reload window' later, and the import was fixed. Hope this helps :)